# Knockout js Button works in IE 11 but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have 3 buttons with some display logic behind. Does are working flawless in IE 11 but not in Chrome. I have currently no idea what the problem is.

Here is one of the 3 buttons

```
<div data-bind="click: conConfirmTransmit, visible: currentProcessStatusProgramCode() === 'CONSULTING', enable: isAllowedToConfirmAndTransmit" class="confirm-button">
```

Step Forward

Depending on the logic i set `isAllowedToConfirmAndTransmit` to true/false

Any idea what is wrong with the code? The button is in my case allways visible

Comment: Please add your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

seemed to work for me and I'm running chrome  however I don't think an enable binding is going to work on a div.  why aren't you using a button?

```js
function vm() {
 this.currentProcessStatusProgramCode = ko.observable('CONSULTING');
 this.isAllowedToConfirmAndTransmit = ko.observable(true);
 this.conConfirmTransmit = function(){
  alert('conConfirmTransmit');
 }
 
}

var mymodel = new vm();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```css
.confirmbutton{
 display:block;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:#bbb #888 #666 #aaa;
 border-width:3px 4px 4px 3px;
 width:9em;
 height:2em;
 background:#ccc;
 color:#333;
 line-height:2;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:900;
}
.confirmbutton:hover{
 border-color: #666 #aaa #bbb #888;
 border-width:4px 3px 3px 4px;
 color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div data-bind="click: conConfirmTransmit, visible: currentProcessStatusProgramCode() === 'CONSULTING', enable: isAllowedToConfirmAndTransmit" class="confirmbutton">click me </div>
<br>
change program code: <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: currentProcessStatusProgramCode"/>
 
<p>
is Allowed Confirm & Transmit <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isAllowedToConfirmAndTransmit">
</p>
```